# ¿Cómo aletar al usuario antes de abandonar una tarea? (onExit, onRefresh)

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de evaluación bastante simple, pero el punto es que en una misma pantalla un usuario puede ir agregando elementos dinámicos y posteriormente llenar información.

El problema viene que si un usuario (ya sea por error u otro motivo) desea refrescar o cerrar la pestaña, se alerte sobre los cambios pendientes o bien de la perdida de su avance; algo así como lo hace Facebook cuando dejas una publicación a medias y deseas salir de la pestaña.

¿Cuál es el evento que se activa? o ¿qué función se debe registrar para ello?

```
// Se ejecuta si el usuario trata de salir con cambios pendientes.
document.addEventListener('leave', fn (evt) {});
```

Imagino que de una forma requiero también notificar al navegador que hay «cosas» pendientes ¿correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el evento **Window.onbeforeunload** para retornar una función, que en este caso, evite que el usuario abandone antes de guardar los datos

```
var _msg = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = _msg;
  if (typeof e == 'undefined') {
    e = window.event;
  }
  if (e) {
    window.confirm(_msg);
    e.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;  
}
```

1. En primer caso hemos definido una variable que contiene el texto que queremos que se muestre en la alerta al usuario.
2. Declaramos el evento **Window.onbeforeunload** que nos retornará una función anónima.
3. Antes de realizar cualquier otra operación es de buena costumbre comprobar que el evento que ha llamado a esta función no sea nulo. `if (typeof e == 'undefined')`
4. Una vez tengamos esto podemos mostrar en pantalla una notificación **confirm()** la cual tiene dos acciones de retorno, **Aceptar** y **Cancelar** o **true** y **false**.
5. Por último retornamos por medio del evento definido.

Esto también funciona en caso de intentar volver hacia atrás en el **History** del navegador o intentar refrescar la ventana del navegador.

[**Window.onbeforeunload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

[**Window.confirm()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Espero que te sea de gran ayuda.